# Jquery validator not working for data-role="tagsinput" textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to validate the input text box data against a list of array fields. Below is my sample code:

Method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateClass", function (value, element,options) {
    return data.indexOf(value) != -1;
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control sampleClass" id="sample" placeholder="Sample data" name="sample[]" />
```

Jquery:

```
   $("#sample").each(function () {
        $(this).rules('add', {
                required: true,
                validateClass : true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Value is required",
                    validateClass : "Validation failed"
                }
            });
    });
```

The above combinations works perfectly well. Now I have more than one data in the input text box . I used bootstrap tag inputs to add more than one input. So I changed the code for HTML to:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sample" placeholder="Sample data" name="sampler" data-role="tagsinput"/>
```

I am able to add multiple input data, but the validation method is not called. Please do not mark this question as duplicate. The jQuery validate for the textbox doesn't work whenever I add `data-role="tagsinput"` for the corresponding textbox.

Please advise.

Comment: Here's an [example from google](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-tagsinput/) - does this resolve the issue you're encountering?

Comment: this one is paid formvalidation.io using bootstrapvalidator. It did not work

Comment: can you see in the browser inspector how are those tags' text really stored in the inputs?

Comment: if i use $(this).val(). I am console.log comma seperated values

Comment: For jQuery Validate, you cannot have more than one input element with the same name... `name="sample[]"` ~ naming **must** be unique; `name="sample[0]"`, `name="sample[1]"`, `name="sample[2]"`, etc.  It's in the docs and discussed numerous times on SO.

Comment: It did not solve the issue as I tried it with single input box. Removed the sampleclass from class and used with id #sample for the rules. Still it does not call the validator method .

Comment: @Sparky - my concern was, it works when i don't add data-role="tagsinput" on the html input text line. When I use data-role="tagsinput" for adding multiple values in the same textbox it doesn't work.